# context_info and nvarchar - additional characters on select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to set the CONTEXT_INFO with some values (stored as NVARCHAR(128)), then in other place read this value and create an xml variable with it. Unfortunatelly on select there is read more characters and don't know how to fix it. 
Code to reproduction:

```
exec dbo.[SetConnectedUser] 'p'

DECLARE @contextInfo VARCHAR(128) = NULLIF(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() as VARCHAR(128)), '')

SELECT @contextInfo AS 'ContextInfo'
FOR XML PATH('Message')

select @contextInfo, len(@contextInfo)
```

The @contextInfo variable returns what I set to the stored procedure, in this case 'p'. But length of this variable is 128.

The created xml toolks that:

```
<Message>
<ContextInfo>p&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;</ContextInfo>
</Message>
```

How to remove these unnecessary characters?

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[SetConnectedUser](@userId VARCHAR(128))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @context VARBINARY(128)

    SET @context = CAST(@UserId AS VARBINARY(128))

    --SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x0
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @context
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@contextInfo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, CHAR(0) , '')
```